# Pandas group time into periods starting at different times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series with irregular frequency of samples. To get useful data of this, I need to find 10 minute periods with roughly evenly spaced samples (this I have defined the average timedelta between 2 samples is less than 20s).

**Example Data:**
(For the sake of this example, I will make it 10s intervals with avg 2s deltas.)

```
| timestamp             | speed |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:12   | 10    |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:14   | 14    |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:16   | 12    |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:27   | 18    |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:28   | 19    |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:29   | 19    |
```

The result I am hoping for is a grouping like follows. Note that the second group does not get included because the samples are bunched together at the end of the 10s period (27, 28, 29) which means an implicit extra time gap of 7s which makes the average delta 3s.

```
| timestamp             | avg   | std  | std_over_avg |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:10   | 12    | 1.63 | 0.136        |
```

**EDIT:**
I think I was combining multiple things in my question (and some incorrectly) so I would like to correct/clarify what I am looking for.

Referring back to the example data, I would like to group it into irregular peiords of 10s; that is, if there is a gap of data the next 10s period should start from the timestamp of the next viable rcord. (Please ignore the previous mention of evenly spaced samples, turns out I misinterpreted that requirement, and I can always filter it out at a later stage if need be). So I would want something like this:

```
| period                                     | count | avg   |  std | std_over_avg |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:12 - 2010-01-01 09:20:22  | 3     | 12    | 1.63 | 0.136        |
| 2010-01-01 09:20:27 - 2010-01-01 09:20:37  | 3     | 18.6  | 0.577| 0.031        |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method for achieving most of what I wanted but it is ugly and slow. Hopefully someone can use this as a starting point to develop something more useful:

```py
group_num = 0
cached_future_time = None
def group_by_time(df, ind):
    global group_num 
    global cached_future_time  
    curr_time = ind
    future_time = ind + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    # Assume records are sorted chronologically ascending for this to work.    
    end = df.index.get_loc(future_time, method='pad')  
    start = df.index.get_loc(curr_time)
    num_records = end - start
    if cached_future_time is not None and curr_time < cached_future_time:
        pass
    elif cached_future_time is not None and curr_time >= cached_future_time:
        group_num += 1
        # Only increase the cached_future_time mark if we have sufficient data points to make this group useful.
        if num_records >= 30:
            cached_future_time = future_time
    elif cached_future_time is None:
        cached_future_time = future_time
    return group_num

grp = df.groupby(lambda x: group_by_time(df, x))
```

**Edit:**

Ok I found a much more Pandas-ic way to do this which also significantly faster  than the ugly loop above. My downfall in the above answer was thinking that I needed to do most of the work for calculating the groups in the groupby function (and thinking there wasn't a way to apply such a method across all the rows intelligently).

```py
# Add 10min to our timestamp and shift the values in that column 30 records
# into the future. We can then find all the timestamps that are 30 records
# newer but still within 10min of the original timestamp (ensuring that we have a 10min group with
# at least 30 records).
records["future"] = records["timestamp"] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
starts = list(records[(records["timestamp"] <= records.future.shift(30)) & records.group_num.isnull()].index)

group_num = 1
# For each of those starting timestamps, grab a slice up to 10min in the future
# and apply a group number. 
for start in starts:
    group = records.loc[start:start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10), 'group_num']
    if len(group[group.isnull()]) >= 30:
        # Only apply group_num to null values so that we get disjoint groups (no overlaps).
        group[group.isnull()] = group_num
        group_num += 1
```